# Is there the equivalent of “<ant antfile=xxx/>” in maven pom.xml?

Tags: maven, ant, jar

I have two project which used to be built by ant. I called them P1 and P2, P1 is a java project and P2 is a web project. P2 will include P1 as a jar file. In the past, when I build P2, I can add `<ant antfile="${common}/../build.xml" inheritAll="false"></ant>` into `build.xml` to make P1 to a jar file first, and then copy the jar to P2's lib folder.

Now I will convert both of them to Maven project. I don't know how to imply the process above. I know there are some ways to run `ant` in maven process. But now P1 is a maven project, too. How can I deal with this problem? I want to make a P1.jar before package P2, and I really don't think it is necessary to deploy or install P1.jar to maven repo first. Is there any convenient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you converting an Ant project to Maven? Is there some issue that you're trying to resolve with the build? Or, do you think Maven is better, and thus you need to rewrite everything in Maven? Don't touch stuff that works. There's enough broken stuff you can manage.

In Maven, you could make these two independent projects:

- P1 would build the jar and deploy this jar into your local Maven repository.
- When P2 builds, it would fetch that pre-built P1 jar from your Maven repository.

You can use [Jfrog's Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) or [Sonatype's Maven](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) as your local Maven repo.

You could also structure the two projects as [subprojects](http://i-proving.com/2007/03/29/Split-Your-Project-Into-Sub-Projects/). In this scenario, P1 and P2 would be two sub projects, and you'd have a P3 with pretty much nothing but a `pom.xml` that would build both projects.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The decision to converting ant to maven is made by our team, because our svn server has a lot of jar files that are reduplicated. We have a nexus server to control our jars, but I have another problem that P1 is also used by a project we can call it P4, when we use ant to build, there is no problem. How can I structure the three projects in maven? Can I run mvn install to install P1.jar automaticly before building other projects?

Comment: @lbear declare P1 as a dependency in the pom files of the projects that depend on P1.

Comment: @lbear Before you go converting to Maven take a look at [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/). Ivy integrates with your current Ant builds. All you have to do is to create an `ivy.xml` to declare your first level jar dependencies (just like you would with Maven), and download the jars via `<ivy:retrieve>`. You get the same Maven dependency resolution, but can pretty much keep your old build system intact. For new projects, I prefer Maven over Ant w/ Ivy, but with old projects using Ivy gives you 90% of what Maven would, but without having to restructure everything.

Comment: @lbear Excellent book on Ivy with Ant is [Manning's Ant in Action](http://www.manning.com/loughran/). Safari Books on Line has it in their collection.